# How to read from a text file and change text of a react element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have this website I am working on and I have a snippet of code like this;

```
<div data-layer="0e50f80e-132b-476b-b316-3a8b6a4593e6" className="item1Title">Item 1 Title</div>
```

I want to be able to change the title of the object without hardcoding every change, it would be great if I could read the title from a text file in case I need to change and update content. But this solution would be great also if it allows me to change it from a parent component instead of hard coding that change into the file. (I use a program that helps autogenerate some jsx and I don't want to have to redo a bunch of work every time!)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access to files from reactjs you need to call an api or you need to launch a service nodejs ( Socket IO ) you can use to read/Write files

Comment: I know that haha, Im just asking how to change the text of that class from a different component?

Comment: you can pass the document.getElementById as props parameters and change it inside the component